# Can a cathode tube light be run off a battery?

Tags: connector, light

I have two cathode tubes I bought for my computer case back in the day. they are the standard sata connection to the PSU.

My question is can I change the plug end that of a 9V battery or is this simply not enough juice? Or if I where to wire it up to a main sock in the UK (240V) what would I need to do to stop the excess. Is mains a total bad idea?

Comment: What is a cathode tube?  A TV?  And what are you doing putting your socks in the mains?  Do you have any data sheets for these "cathode tubes"?  We can tell you nothing without knowing what they are and what they require to make them do whatever they do.

Comment: I've never heard of a "cathode tube". All tubes have a cathode by definition, but also a anode. What makes them not "anode tubes", or some other equally obscuring name?  Figure out what these things really are and learn to use the right terms.

Answer (score 2):

****WARNING: The tube drivers decsribed below make a very  higher voltage to operate the tube. Hundreds of volts is typical. Over 1000V occurs on large CCFL units.
 You can get a serious electric shock from these.**

- **If you do not take enough care you MAY die.****

I assume that you mean CCFLs "Cold Cathode Fluorescent Lights".
 Like these -

[image]

IF they ran from the 12V from  a SATA power plug you can run then from 12V. If so they will have had a controller which must be used with them. The controller converts the 12V to a higher voltage.

They may have run from the STA 5V supply - less likely. You need to connect to a SATA power supply socket and measure which voltages appear where **ON THE INPUT TO THE CONTROLLER FROM THE SATA SOCKET**. Do **NOT** try and measure the output voltages from the controller. Cheaper meters may emit magic smoke and meter users in some cases may emit magic smoke as well.

[Useful CCFL page](http://www.byfort.com/ccfllamps.htm)

[CCFL driver IC datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc2973.pdf) - UCC3973 etc - shows what's involved. You do NOT want to build one of there. Commercial units are cheapish.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what your end goal is.
The tubes that you have should have a little box where your tubes connect to. This is usually the inverter that changes the 12volt on the SATA/MOLEX(yellow cable) to thousands of volts. Now you may ask how the hell can it be thousands of volts- the last guy that asked me that and did not believe me had quite a SHOCK! get it! ouch.

Using a 9Volt battery might not get it going. The main issue with tubes is that the initial wattage required to spark the tube is extremly high then once its stable the sustained power is not too bad. Another battery option is tho use LithiumPolymer pre built for 12volt applications or use another circuit to step up voltages. Batteries are not a great solution for these lights- Go with LED's instead.Easier to connect and use lot less energy.

[image]

You see the greens spike peak- That is the maximum current it will draw to start- then you can notice how it drops and tries to equalise afterwards.(This graph is an example only and might not represent exactly what is being discussed here and should not be used as guide)
That spike is the main reason a 9volt battery will just not work and it is the main reason for the depletion of power in the battery cells. The same applies to home tubes-even enegery saving ones- Its cheaper to turn them on and leave them on for a week rather than turning them on and off several times during the weak,

You would have to be clever and join 2 9volt batteries and use a voltage regulating transistor to keep 12volts.

If you want to plug it into mains you have to have an extra component to convert AC-DC 
[Using a rectifier circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier)
There are ones with transformers or rectifing diode. The easist probalby will tbe buy universal power converter.
[image]
Or try and salvage an old one at home- check the label and make sure it says 12volts then check which one is + and - and connect it to your tubes. If you want to connect more and more tubes you will have to find an adapter with more Amps on output.